# Holomorphic function on a closed and bounded set.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I have trouble with a little part of a proof in my textbook.

> Consider a holomorphic function $f$ on a open set $G$. Let $\partial K(a,r)$ be the boundary of a disc  contained in $G$ with center a and
>   radius r.

**My question is:**

> How can I deduce that $\sup \lbrace \vert f(w) \vert \vert w\in\partial K(a,r) \rbrace <\infty$. My textbook uses the argument that the statement is true, because $\partial K(a,r)$ is bounded and closed. But where does this come from? A theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Holomorphic functions are in particular continuous, and closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are compact. A continuous function on a compact domain is bounded.

Comment: This implies that any holomorphic function on a bounded set is bounded, right?